# How do I make calls to Riot API with Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make calls to https://tr.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/TR/v2.5/league/by-summoner/12312312?key , but I get an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error. So I add https://tr.api.riotgames.com; but chrome gives me an error. How can I make calls to https://tr.api.riotgames.com/someurl?

Btw, https://tr.api.riotgames.com wont response if you type directly.

Comment: How are you making the calls? Also, try using in permissions "https://tr.api.riotgames.com/*"

Comment: @juvian I tried that, it gives an error and keeps previous version.

Comment: @juvian Oh ı see that asterisk now, I will try it.

Comment: @juvian Permission 'http://tr.api.riotgames.com*' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.

Comment: Yes it needs a / before the asterisk but comments won´t let me put it :P. Also need the https and such part

Comment: With a slash, it worked! Let me test it.

Comment: @juvian It worked, thank you for saving my day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add https://tr.api.riotgames.com to permissions, it only considers that specific page to be able to make requests. If you want to make a call to an url from that domain, correct sintax is https://tr.api.riotgames.com/*.

It is always good practice to use as specific as possible though, maybe you can add https://tr.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/* for your case